# DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID - PayPal SDK error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, paypal

Currently making an Android app and decided to integrate Paypal payment in it, so that the user is redirected to Paypal payment inside the app.

I found the Paypal SampleApp for what I want to do:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK. 
Firstly, I tested it and it worked without errors with CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK, and with the default sandbox sample acc (usr: sample@buy.com, pass:123123123).

Then I made an account on developer.paypal.com in order to make the payment to my Paypal account (with CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT set to PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION). I created an app and used the provided Client ID from the developer portal in the SampleApp. By doing that, the payment isn't completed, and gives the error:

```
request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:Bad Request
request failed with server response:{"name":"DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID","debug_id":"9f83f9a8ce3e5","message":"The value of PayPal-Request-Id header has already been used","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/","details":[]}
DUPLICATE_REQUEST_ID
```

Note: I'm only using the "BUY A THING" option in the Sample App; not interested in the other options

The code of the class that handles the payment process:

```
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalAuthorization;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalItem;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalOAuthScopes;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ShippingAddress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PaymentActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = "PAYMENT";
    private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

    private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "i changed this field with my client id";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING = 3;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
            .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
        PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

     intent.putExtra(com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
    }

    private PayPalPayment getThingToBuy(String paymentIntent) {
        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.0"), "USD", "DRINK",
                paymentIntent);
    }

    /*
     * This method shows use of optional payment details and item list.
     */

    public void onFuturePaymentPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT);
    }

    public void onProfileSharingPressed(View pressed) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentActivity.this, PayPalProfileSharingActivity.class);

        // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_REQUESTED_SCOPES, getOauthScopes());

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING);
    }

    private PayPalOAuthScopes getOauthScopes() {
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>(
                Arrays.asList(PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_EMAIL, PayPalOAuthScopes.PAYPAL_SCOPE_ADDRESS) );
        return new PayPalOAuthScopes(scopes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        /**
                         *  TODO: send 'confirm' (and possibly confirm.getPayment() to your server for verification
                         * or consent completion.
                         * See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                         * for more details.
                         *
                         * For sample mobile backend interactions, see
                         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
                         */
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        TAG,
                        "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FUTURE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Future Payment code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("FuturePaymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("FuturePaymentExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "FuturePaymentExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            }
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_SHARING) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PayPalAuthorization auth =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PayPalProfileSharingActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_AUTHORIZATION);
                if (auth != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", auth.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                        String authorization_code = auth.getAuthorizationCode();
                        Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", authorization_code);

                        sendAuthorizationToServer(auth);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Profile Sharing code received from PayPal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("ProfileSharingExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("ProfileSharingExample", "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.i(
                        "ProfileSharingExample",
                        "Probably the attempt to previously start the PayPalService had an invalid PayPalConfiguration. Please see the docs.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendAuthorizationToServer(PayPalAuthorization authorization) {

        /**
         * TODO: Send the authorization response to your server, where it can
         * exchange the authorization code for OAuth access and refresh tokens.
         *
         * Your server must then store these tokens, so that your server code
         * can execute payments for this user in the future.
         *
         * A more complete example that includes the required app-server to
         * PayPal-server integration is available from
         * https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/samples/mobile_backend
         */

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop service when done
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the error occurs because the PayPal app is also installed on my phone. If I uninstall it, the payment is successfully done in the PRODUCTION environment.

PayPal will soon release a version of their app that patches this bug: 
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/272.